# Bootstrap grid table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

How can i make this draw ?
first box black  col-lg-2
Second box red col-lg-4
third box col-lg-6 > contain ( one green box col-lg-8 )
                             ( 4 blue boxes in `<li>` col-lg-4 )

just like this picture

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking it's a shame that CSS tables don't have rowspan and colspan properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily nest columns. Try to do it like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">black</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">red</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">green</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">blue</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">blue</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">blue</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">blue</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately last 4 blue boxes related with <li>

Comment: It's not very clear, what you want to do and what the problem is... Maybe you should revise your question and provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I write this as an answer because i can't comment.

You can also put the `li`-element inside the nested `row` with `col-*`-elements.